# Error creating topic in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

When using the command:

> /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181
>   --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized option: --create
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am following the instructions in the Kafka: The Definitive Guide book.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to run the correct script: /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh? In your question you are not including the last "s".

Comment: Also you are using both the --describe as well as the --create command, which does not work. If leave one of them out it should work (depending on what you want to do, create or describe a topic).

Comment: The missing "s" was a typo in the question, not my command, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Removing --describe still results in the same error message.

Comment: Clearly you have some basic system setup issue where your Java isn't setup or that Kafka shell script isn't setup correctly. I don't have that book, but have you tried the basic Confluent Platform debian/rpm packages? docs.confluent.io/current/

Comment: Note: I updated the command I used, since I used to wrong command the first time. There is still and error however.

Comment: I have tried confluent, but it didn't work for me either.

Comment: This change worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours.
I was able to make it work by adding **sudo** in the script: /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh

```
exec sudo $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.TopicCommand "$@"
```

Comment: Why was this necessary? Surely this is a workaround and not the actual issue? (also, it doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether you have downloaded the correct (compiled) version.

This may happen if you are trying to run the script in the source code version.